# Angularjs route provider change param

Tags: angularjs

There are route

```js
when('/route/:param1/:param2', {
```

That open view with url */route/**param1_value1**/**param2_value2***

In view on button click need redirect to

*/route/**param1_value3**/param2_value2*

How I can from current url get new url

sample

```js
$routeParams.param1 = param1_value3;
$location.path($routeParams.url()); //< /route/param1_value3/param2_value2
```

Answer (score 1):

Change param value with move to new location

```js
controllers.controller('...Ctrl', ['$route', '$routeParams' ...

$routeParams.id = newId;
$route.updateParams($routeParams);
```